# Limit of quotient of two infinite series $\left(\frac{0}{0}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,k}<\infty$. I want to calculate  $$L=\lim_{k\to \infty}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,k}\over\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,k+1}}$$ if I know that $\lim_{k\to \infty} |a_{n,k}/a_{n,k+1}|=1$. I think $L=1$, or $\lim_{k\to \infty}|a_{n,k}/a_{n,k+1}|$ in general, but I am stuck.

***EDIT:*** $a_{n,k}\to0$ and $\sum_{n}a_{n,k}\to0$ as $k\to\infty$. (If it cannot be done in general, I might try to evaluate it directly, however the sum is extremely complicated). Also, $a_{n,k}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

***EDIT:*** Is it true that if $\lim_{k\to \infty} \left|a_{n,k}/a_{n,k+1}\right|=1$ the following holds?
$$L=\lim_{k\to \infty}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,k}\left|\frac{a_{n,k+1}}{a_{n,k}}\right|\over\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,k}}=\frac{1}{L}$$

Comment: Seems to need some boundedness condition too, like $\sum_{n=1}^{∞}a_{n,k} > 0$, for all $k$ larger than some sufficiently large value $K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $a_{k,k} = c_k$, and for all $n \neq k$, set something like $a_{n,k} = 1/(nk)^{nk}$. Here the $c_k$ can be any sequence of positive numbers as long as $c_k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. Then clearly since $a_{n,n}$ is the only strange term for given $n$, your ratio and difference limits will hold for all $n$, and also $\sum_n a_{n,k} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. However, the series for each $k$ will be largely dominated by $a_{k,k}$ as long as the $c_k$ are chosen properly with respect to summation $\sum_{n \neq k} a_{n,k}$. And you can set the ratios $c_k / c_{k+1}$ to basically anything you want greater than $1$ for each $k$ as long as the $c_k$ tend to zero and the ratios are bounded. Thus it should be possible to get any limit (at least finite limit) greater than or equal to $1$ that you want for the ratio of series, or if you want, have the limit not exist.

Comment: So you mean $L\ge 1$? If it is true, then I can continue, since in my formula $L>1$ is not possible, so for my specific series $L=1$.

Comment: @pndev I'm not sure if that's guaranteed or not. I'll have to think about it.

Comment: Added one more criteria. Brb tommorrow, I recollect everything about it.

Comment: @pndev Yes I thought about it and as long as your ratio is the $k$th series divided by the $k+1$th series (i.e., it's not written upside-down), then it's impossible to get a limit $L < 1$ that exists, because then your series would not converge to zero as $k \to \infty$, which was one of your conditions. (In fact, you would get that $\sum_{n} a_{n,k} \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$ if the limit $L < 1$ exists). However it's still technically possible to have infinitely many of the ratios to be greater than 1 and infinitely many less than 1, so that the limit of ratios does not exist.

Comment: @pndev That sounds exciting. I don't mean to discourage you, but usually when something like that pops up, and it seems like something so "difficult" is proved, it usually means that there's a gap or mistake somewhere. Hopefully it's not in my answer. I'd recommend posting a write-up to math.arxiv to establish that you are the first one that came up with the proof approach, and then go to math.overflow (research mathematics) and post your proposed proof in its entirety (or give a link to the arxiv copy), so that people who are really good at research math can review it.